# Display images one after another with few seconds delay

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I want to display two images from database when user clicks a button. But 2nd image should display after 5 seconds of delay of displaying image 1. I tried using `sleep(5)` like this

```
//Image extraction query
$c1 = mysqli_query($con, "") or die (mysqli_query($con));
$c2 = mysqli_fetch_array($c1) or die (mysqli_error($con));
 echo '<div class="col-xs-12">

       <div class="col-xs-5">
<img src='. $c2['bpic'].' /></div>'; // 1st Image
sleep(5);
echo '<div class="col-xs-5">
<img src='. $c2['apic'].' /></div>';
```

Tried using `setInterval` with `load` in jquery but it reloads the `<div>` every 5 seconds.

Can somebody guide me how to do this?

But whole page waits for 5 seconds to load. Then both the images will display together.

**EDIT**

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var autoLoad = setInterval(
   function ()
   {
      $('#loadpic').load('load_pic.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>').fadeIn("slow");
   }, 5000); // refresh page every 5 seconds
</script>
```

HTML

```
echo '<div class="col-xs-5" id="loadpic" style="display:none;">
<img src='. $c2['apic'].' /></div>';
```

Comment: REmember PHP runs on the server and builds your page. Nothing you do in PHP will cause a time delay in what happens on the browser other than as you say causing the page to take longer to load

Comment: Your javascript `setInterval()` was the right approach. So you had better ask another quesiton and show that code so we can see what you did wrong

Comment: `setInterval()` is just plain javascript, not jquery. If you want it to only happen once, you'd want to use `setTimeout()`. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I have edited my code. That is what i tried but it reloads for every 5 secs. After image displays it has to stop

Comment: You need to either fetch each image individually (make individual calls to the PHP file for them), or you need to have the second image hidden to start with and then make it visible after 5 seconds using `setTimeout()`.  _How_ you show/hide them would depend on whether or not you want to have the hidden image take up space or not.  You are currently calling a function every 5 seconds that loads _both_ images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript for client-side manimulation...

Use setTimeout for one event...

```js
  setTimeout(function(){
      $('#img2').show();// or slideDown();  or fadeIn();      
  }, 5000);//wait 5 sec
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12">
   <div class="col-xs-5">
      <img src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12" style="display:none;" id="img2">
   <div class="col-xs-5">
      <img src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
   </div>
</div>
```